# Why is the inferred return type of this Typescript function adding string type union to array type

Tags: typescript

Given the following function:

```
export const createLetterGroups = (dynamicKey: string) => {
  const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  return letters.map(letter => ({
    letter,
    [dynamicKey]: [{ test: 'string1' }, { test: 'string2' }]
  }));
};
```

Typescript is inferring the following return type:

```
const createLetterGroups: (dynamicKey: string) => {
    [x: string]: string | {
        test: string;
    }[];
    letter: string;
}[]
```

Why is it typing the dynamic property as:

```
string | {
        test: string;
    }[]
```

instead of just:

```
{
    test: string;
}[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript handles type inference different for dynamic property names. I believe the reason for this case is essentially that it's possible for your `dynamicKey` string to actually *be* the string `'letter'`.

This isn't technically related to the type being returned by a function, and the same behaviour can be replicated with just a variable assignment:

````js
declare const num: number;
declare const str: string;

/**
 * Inferred type:
 * ```
 * {
 *   [x: string]: number | string;
 *   num: number;
 * }
 * ```
 */
const bar = {
  num,
  [str]: str,
};
````

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3igrgWwC5t8AjEGAbgChRJYFl0tMYiWBLFAc2qoHoAVAKrwB8AJIoAZuTjB4GAJ4AHEARFiABto3wA3rvjwA2gA82GGJy4BdIrjxkY8AD7wO3aqKPFCvp15iAL662poafFSMmPAksPAAvPoivgA0KcYsdu6W6UHUQA)

Consider the case where, in this example, the name of the dynamic property is `num`. In that case, the resulting object would be `{ num: 'num' }`, so in order to allow for this possibility TypeScript has to infer that the type of the dynamic key could be a string.

However, as far as I can tell TypeScript doesn't seem to change its inferred type based on the order of properties. Whereas JavaScript *does* care about the order of properties when creating an object, at least in the case where there are duplicate keys - the last one overwrites any earlier ones.

If you know that the object you're constructing is definitely typed differently to what TypeScript has inferred, then you may want to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what it doesn't already know.

Though I would generally recommend being cautious with using type assertions, since if they're not based on good assumptions it is possible to use them in a way that compromises TypeScript's type checking. They certainly have a place and are useful tools, but it's important to be aware of their drawbacks.

---

Here's a runnable example showing the `{ num: 'num' }` example I mentioned above:

```js
const num = 3;
const str = 'num';

const foo = ((str: string, num: number) => {
  const bar = {
    num,
    [str]: str,
  };

  return bar;
})(str, num);

console.log(foo);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbGBeGBmA3AKFJW0ATqjAOQKKk67jQwBmIIJAFC0QFwxECWYA5gBo4SLhQBGAU0IBKVAD4YAb2wwYeOuICGxNCrVqKg1QYDaRALpcixtQF9qawpKjxCYGNsI47M9lEJhChlqDRAAG0kAOnCQfhZGEBDsIA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, you may want to edit the part that says `In that case, the resulting object would be { num: 'num' }` because that doesn't look correct

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had been thinking of an earlier iteration of the example where I'd given the variables vales. I'll update my answer to be more consistent

Comment: Oh, actually no I my example is correct. I'll upate my answer to be include a runnable example to demonstrate that